# Decoding server error message and finding the source

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm running Wordpress 3.5.1 on a shared hosting server. I'm trying to go through and remove all of the plug-ins that give me problems.

Can you point me in the right direction to find the source of this server error (s)? It's actually a set of errors that are appearing together and to my noob-self look related..

Maybe something from "bbp" is BBPress?

```
20130516T014859: www.hippressurecooking.com/index.php 
WordPress database error Query execution was interrupted for query SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_bbp_login_widget' LIMIT 1 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), call_user_func_array, wp_widgets_init, do_action('widgets_init'), call_user_func_array, WP_Widget_Factory->_register_widgets, WP_Widget->_register, WP_Widget->get_settings, get_option 
WordPress database e 

20130516T014859: lastwww.hippressurecooking.com/index.php 
WordPress database error Query execution was interrupted for query SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = '_bbp_theme_package_id' LIMIT 1 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('setup_theme'), call_user_func_array, bbp_setup_theme, do_action('bbp_setup_theme'), call_user_func_array, bbPress->setup_theme, bbp_get_theme_package_id, get_option 
WordPress database error MySQL server has gone aw 

20130516T014859: www.hippressurecooking.com/index.php 
WordPress database error Query execution was interrupted for query SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_image' LIMIT 1 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), call_user_func_array, wp_widgets_init, do_action('widgets_init'), call_user_func_array, WP_Widget_Factory->_register_widgets, WP_Widget->_register, WP_Widget->get_settings, get_option 
WordPress database error MySQL
```

Comment: does it take a long time to get the interruption ? could it be a timeout from the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the plugins one by one to see the one causing the problem, or disable them all and enable them one by one. Once you've found the one causing problem, check if it's up-to-date, try to reinstall it, try to check on the plugin's forums to see if someone else had the same problem, and if nothing work try to find another one which do the same thing.